# switch statement case not executed

Tags: php

like this i have above 40 case statements some conditions no even executed i don't know why please answer thanks

```
switch (true){
    case (isset($_POST['min_beds']) && !empty($_POST['price_val']) && isset($_POST['property_status']) && $_POST['property_type'] == 'All' && $_POST['my_project_location'] == 'All'): 
    break;
    case (isset($_POST['min_beds']) && !empty($_POST['price_val']) && isset($_POST['my_project_location']) && $_POST['property_type'] == 'All' && $_POST['property_status'] == 'All'): 
    break;
    case (isset($_POST['min_beds']) && !empty($_POST['price_val']) && isset($_POST['property_status']) && $_POST['property_type'] == 'All' && $_POST['my_project_location'] == 'All'):
    break;

    case ($_POST['property_status'] == 'All' && isset($_POST['property_type']) && isset($_POST['my_project_location'])  && isset($_POST['min_beds']) && isset($features) && !empty($_POST['price_val'])): 
    break;
    case (isset($features) && !empty($_POST['price_val']) && isset($_POST['my_project_location']) && $_POST['property_status'] == 'All' && $_POST['property_type'] == 'All' && $_POST['min_beds'] == 'All'): 
    break;
    case ($_POST['property_status'] == 'All' && isset($_POST['my_project_location'])  && isset($_POST['min_beds']) && isset($features) && !empty($_POST['price_val']) && $_POST['property_type'] == 'All'): 
    break;
  }
```

Comment: This is not how switch statements works. This is not what it is for. Use `if`s

Comment: already use else if it not work correctly i need to move some condition top of the  code then it execute. here also work like that.

Comment: *This is not how switch statements works.* ii executes only the first condition with true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch works more like a chain of `elseif`'s than a series of `if`'s. Only the first `case` statement that evaluates to true *(when non-strictly compared to the value being switched on)* will be considered a match and no further `case` statements will be checked. Once the first `break` is reached following the matching `case` statement, the switch will exit;

see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

```
switch(true) {
    case true:
        echo("this will run");
    case false: 
        echo("this will also run because there is no 'break' yet");
        break;
    case true:
        echo("this will never run");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using switch correctly. If what you want is to break when any of these conditions are met use ifs.

```
if(isset($_POST['min_beds']) && !empty($_POST['price_val']) && isset($_POST['property_status']) && $_POST['property_type'] == 'All' && $_POST['my_project_location'] == 'All'){
    break;
}
if(isset($_POST['min_beds']) && !empty($_POST['price_val']) && isset($_POST['my_project_location']) && $_POST['property_type'] == 'All' && $_POST['property_status'] == 'All'){ 
    break;
}
if(isset($_POST['min_beds']) && !empty($_POST['price_val']) && isset($_POST['property_status']) && $_POST['property_type'] == 'All' && $_POST['my_project_location'] == 'All'){
    break;
}
if($_POST['property_status'] == 'All' && isset($_POST['property_type']) && isset($_POST['my_project_location'])  && isset($_POST['min_beds']) && isset($features) && !empty($_POST['price_val'])){
    break;
}
if(isset($features) && !empty($_POST['price_val']) && isset($_POST['my_project_location']) && $_POST['property_status'] == 'All' && $_POST['property_type'] == 'All' && $_POST['min_beds'] == 'All'){ 
    break;
}
if($_POST['property_status'] == 'All' && isset($_POST['my_project_location'])  && isset($_POST['min_beds']) && isset($features) && !empty($_POST['price_val']) && $_POST['property_type'] == 'All'){ 
    break;
  }
```

Comment: `break` will do nothing without being inside a control structure such as a loop or switch statement.

Comment: His original switch doesn't do anything either. I assumed he was already in a loop he wanted to get out of based on his initial post.

Comment: If you look at the actual code, it is pretty clear that this would NOT be inside any sort of loop. What would be the purpose of repeatedly checking global variables for the presence of keys?

Comment: it's a filter ,word press  taxonomy and meta query compare and display the posts

Comment: else if(!isset($features) && $_POST['property_status'] == 'All' && $_POST['min_beds'] == 'All' && $_POST['property_type'] == 'All' && $_POST['my_project_location'] == 'All'){
      $args = array( 
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'property',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
      ); 
  }